# ArcGIS Pro: Control which cities are labelled on the basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, layouts, basemap

I am creating a zoomed in map of a city (Nottingham, UK), and on the layout I have an extent indicator, showing where Nottingham is found in relation to the rest of the UK.

On the extent indicator map, I am using the topographic basemap. Automatically, the only city it has labelled is London, which I don't want. Is there any way to turn off the labelling for London, and make it say Nottingham instead?

[image]

Comment: Is Nottingham supposed to be the red point or the white point?

Comment: Nottingham is supposed to be the red point. The white point is London, which has come up automatically. I want to remove this.

Comment: Are both layers shapefiles, rasters, or a combination?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The red point is the extent indicator (which I want to keep), the white point is on the basemap (which I want to remove).

Comment: No, one problem with a web mapping service like your base map is that you do not have the ability to turn on or off labels like you wish.  It looks like you have added some data for Nottingham.  You could add a Nottingham label to your inset.  Alternatively, you could find data for European countries and build your own base map.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.

Comment: Not for esri basemaps. Probably easier to turn off the basemap and use feature classes with the countries/cities you want visible and labeled.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use a different basemap, then use one of the basemaps that has a separate "reference" layer, such as the "Light Grey Canvas" basemap.  These basemaps include TWO (or more) layers, one of which is a "reference" layer that includes cities, roads labels, etc.

You can turn this "reference" layer on/off separately in the table of contents, even though it is part of the basemap.

So turn off the "reference" layer, and you're good to go.

Here's how it looks some of the basemaps that have a separate "reference" layer...

World Ocean basemap:

[image]

Light Grey Canvas basemap:

[image]

National Geographic Style:

[image]